# Typescript + Express : Type 'typeof e' has no compatible call signatures

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, webpack

I'm trying to build an application using typescript , express . but i'm getting this error : 
`Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'typeof e' has no compatible call signatures`(in app.ts where express() is called )

I'm using webpack here to help with my development.

My Package.json :

```
"scripts" :{
    "build": "webpack" 
 },
 "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "dotenv": "^6.1.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/body-parser": "^1.17.0",
    "@types/dotenv": "^4.0.3",
    "@types/express": "^4.16.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.19",
    "ts-loader": "^5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "^7.0.1",
    "typescript": "^3.1.6",
    "webpack": "^4.24.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
  }
```

my `webpack.confg.js` :

```
var path = require("path");
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require("clean-webpack-plugin");

var fs = require("fs");
var nodeModules = {};
fs.readdirSync("node_modules")
  .filter(function(x) {
    return [".bin"].indexOf(x) === -1;
  })
  .forEach(function(mod) {
    nodeModules[mod] = "commonjs " + mod;
  });

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.ts",

  plugins: [new CleanWebpackPlugin(["./dist"])],
  output: {
    filename: "index.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      //all files with .ts extention will be handled y ts-loader
      { test: /\.ts$/, loader: "ts-loader" }
    ]
  },
  target: "node",
  externals: nodeModules
};
```

my `app.ts` :

```
import * as express from "express";
import * as bodyParser from "body-parser";

class App {
  public app: express.Application;
  constructor() {
    this.app = express();
    this.config();
  }

  private config(): void {
    //add support for application/json type for data
    this.app.use(bodyParser.json());

    //support application/x-www-form-urlencoded post data
    this.app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
  }
}

export default new App().app;
```

I'm running `npm run build` and my build fails with the error stated . 
tried searching for solution in a few blogs and none have mentioned tanything about this error .I manged to add `express.Application` as type for `app` in side `app.ts`
What am i doing wrong ?  Is it because of the configuration of webpack ?

Any help appreciated

Comment: Is `express` missing in your dependencies?

Comment: @pzaenger yes i think i missed it . but its still the same :( . error persists after adding express

Comment: Isn't there any information about which line the error happens?

Comment: @ZeroCho it was at the same place where i'm calling  ``express()`` . i think i solved it . Just changed the import to : ``import express from "express"`` . it solved the issue . @pzaenger , thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: Did you turn on `esModuleInterop` option in tsconfig?

Comment: @ZeroCho yes i have it as ``true``

Comment: Why are you using webpack to develop a server-side app?

Comment: @pzaenger why does `import express from "express"` work whereas `import * as express from "express"` does not?

Comment: In this answer, you can get a detailed explanation of how `esModuleInterop` causes this error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56238356/understanding-esmoduleinterop-in-tsconfig-file

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need to import the default export from express instead of the namespace (which is an object with all named exports).

In your `app.ts` this should be all you need:

```
// Change these
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
```

The difference is:

```
// Namespace import
import * as express from "express";

const app = express.default();

// Default import
import express from "express";

const app = express();
```

Comment: I'm getting this: 
Property 'default' does not exist on type 'typeof e'.

Answer (score 0):

remove "*"

let ur code thats form

```js
import  express  from 'express';

class app {
  public app: express.Application;
  constructor() {
    this.app = express();
    this.app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    this.app.use(express.json());
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

For me, it worked on changing the import as-

```
import { express } from "express";

const app = express();
```

Comment: How did it work for you? It's 100% incorrect.