# TypeScript with Express: Type 'typeof import("express")' has no call signatures

Tags: typescript, express

My error is:

```
Error: src/app.ts(11,13): error TS2349: This expression is not callable.
  Type 'typeof import("express")' has no call signatures.
```

My `tsconfig.json` is:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./built",
        "allowJs": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "esModuleInterop": true
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

My `src/app.ts` has:

```
// const Logger = require('./lib/logger')
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
// const finale = require('finale-rest')
// const morgan = require('morgan')
const DB = require('./models')()


// const resources = require('./resources')

const app = express()
```

The line in question is `const app = express()`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would expect this to work, tried on my machine (with `@types/express` installed) and your code works ..

Comment: Proper solution for TS 2.7+: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56348146/2678608

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add the `@types/express` dependency with `npm i -D @types/express` and then:

```js
import * as express from "express";
...
const app = express();
```

Comment: what do you mean with add? install something or add that line somewhere?

Comment: To install a package via npm, yarn, or whatever package management tool you're using. For example, `npm i --save-dev @types/express` or `yarn add --dev @types/express`.

Answer (score 29):

Make sure you don't have `"esModuleInterop": true` set in tsconfig.json. Disabling this setting resolved the issue for me.

Comment: For me winwiz1's solution was already in place but I was still getting the error. Doing as Nathan Hopper suggested on top of that resolved the issue for me.

Comment: Read this to learn why you should **not** remove "esModuleInterop" from your tsconfig.json: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56348146/2678608  (if you're on TS version 2.7+)

Comment: Yeah but what is if you have references which needs that interop settings like me?

Comment: Solved with this solution, having trouble implementing LRUCache lib, this solved the issue.

Answer (score 26):

To make this work with `"esModuleInterop": true` set to true in your tsconfig.json you can also do this.

```
import * as express from 'express';
...
const app = express.default();
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61595910)

Comment: This answer needs to be upvoted more. I can't believe this solution isn't more widely known.

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue using a CJS module. Neither `import * as ...`, using `default` or toggling `esModuleInterop` worked for me. The code worked but VSCode kept highlighting it as error. Solved it by adding a module declaration file:

```
//foo.d.ts
declare module 'foo'
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error during my adaptation of the Github Starter Project:
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Node-Starter

The problem occured in file 'src/types/express-session-types.d.ts'. (Don't ask me how it works. I am new to Node.js!)

After a clean up of the imports, line 'import session from "express-session-types";' was deleted and this caused the error.
As long as I keep this import - though it seems to be unnecessary - I don't have the error.

file '**src/types/express-session-types.d.ts**':

```
/**
 * Naming this file express-session.d.ts causes imports from "express-session"
 * to reference this file and not the node_modules package.
 */

import session from "express-session-types";

declare module "express-session" {
    export interface SessionData {
        returnTo: string;
    }
}
```

In case this is relevant, file '**app.ts**' contains:

```
import session from "express-session";
...
app.use(session({
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    secret: SESSION_SECRET
}));
```